# Tensorflow control_dependencies not working with list

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a cost, which depends on two list of variables `a` and `b`.
I want to :

1. calculate both gradients of the cost at the current point,
2. update the loss w.r.t. the first list of variables (`a`)
3. update the loss w.r.t. the second list of variable (`b`).

In that order.

To do this I tried something like this:

**EDIT:** Following @Yaroslav Bulatov's answer I tried the following:

```
opt=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001)
grad_cost_wrt_a=opt.compute_gradients(cost,[a])
grad_cost_wrt_b=opt.compute_gradients(cost,[b])

with tf.control_dependencies(grad_cost_wrt_a[0]):
  with tf.control_dependencies(grad_cost_wrt_b[0]):
    update_wrt_a=opt.apply_gradients(grad_cost_wrt_a)
      with tf.control_dependencies([update_wrt_a]):
        update_wrt_b=opt.apply_gradients(grad_cost_wrt_b)
```

Wondering if this is doing the right thing ? If a and b are list of variables.

To be able to then do:

```
sess.run([update_wrt_a,update_wrt_b],feed_dict={x: x_input, y: y_input})
```

First this does not work I get:
cannot convert a list into a Tensor or Operation but control_dependencies is supposed to recieve a list of tensors...

Then bonus question do I really need all those control_dependencies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `grad_cost_wrt_a` and `grad_cost_wrt_b` variables are lists, do something like `grad_cost_wrt_a[0], grad_cost_wrt_b[0]`

Comment: Should have known! sorry I missed it ! Thanks !

Comment: Actually how do you handle the case where a and b are a list of variables ?

Comment: I edited my question ? If I only use a control dependency on the first gradients,variable tuple does it work like I want it to?

Comment: I had to split the first control_dependency into two chained dependencies.